# Determine convergence of integral

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I have the general question: What is to check if an (improper) integral is convergent, semi-convergent or divergent?

That is: How can I see this?

For example, if I've the following integral:

$$ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 + \arctan(\sin(x))}{x^3+2}\,\text{dx}$$

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Add $dx$ maybe ?

Comment: Hint: The numerator is bounded by a function asymptotic to $cx^{-3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integral is convergent if and only if 
$$\int_{0}^t \frac{1+\mathrm{arctan}(\sin(x))}{x^3 +2} \mathrm{dx}$$
admits a limit when $t \rightarrow +\infty$.

You have
$$\int_{0}^t \left| \frac{1+\mathrm{arctan}(\sin(x))}{x^3 +2} \right| \mathrm{dx} \leq \left( 1+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\int_{0}^t  \frac{1}{x^3 +2}  \mathrm{dx} $$

which is a convergent integral. So your integral is absolutely convergent, and therefore convergent.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question. OP was asking about general tactics to solve such problems

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you very much! Why do you take out the product (1+Pi/2) ? That is, how do you know that you should take out (1+Pi/2) ?

Comment: And: Do you have a general "plan" to solve such problems?

Comment: Remember that the function $|\mathrm{arctan}|$ is bounded by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So the numerator is bounded by $1 + \frac{\pi}{2}$. Here, the general technic I used is to compare the given integral with an integral which is well-known to converge. It is quite clear, because the numerator is bounded, that your integral will have the same behavior as $\int \frac{1}{x^3 +2}$. Also note that I used the very important fact that any absolutely convergent integral is convergent (i.e. $\int |f|$ converges implies that $\int f$ converges - whereas the converse is false).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Let's make a test: If I have instead the integral $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ , then the upper boundary is 1. Since $\int_{0}^{t} 1 dt$ is not convergent for $t \to \infty$, the integral is not convergent. Is this true?

Comment: No, you are using it in the wrong sense. The criteria is "if $\int |f| \leq \int g$ and $\int g$ converges, then $\int |f|$ converges". In the case where $\int g$ diverges, you cannot tell anything.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe hm yeah that makes sense. But how could I apply our "trick" with the boundaries?

Comment: You cannot in that case, because $\int_0^{+\infty} \sin(1/t) \mathrm{dt}$ is divergent. So you cannot majore it by a convergent integral.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe OK, but how do you know that $\int_0^{\infty} sin(\frac{1}{t}) dt$ is divergent?

Comment: Substitute $y=1/t$ in the integral, you have $I(x)= \int_1^{x} \sin(\frac{1}{t}) \mathrm{dt} = \int_{1/x}^1 \frac{\sin(y)}{y^2} \mathrm{dy}$. Now using the inequality $\sin(y) \geq y - \frac{y^3}{3}$, you get $I(x) \geq \int_{1/x}^1 \frac{1}{y} - \frac{y}{3} \mathrm{dy} = [\ln(|y|) - \frac{y^2}{6}]_{1/x}^1 = - \frac{1}{6} - \ln(|\frac{1}{x}|) + \frac{1}{6x^2}$ whose limit is $+\infty$ when $x$ goes to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is almost 90 percent. The remaining 10 percent is this answer . The max value of $\arctan(x)$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as the range of arctan is from $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Thus the upper bound of I is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+\frac{\pi}{2}}{x^3+2}dx$ which is convergent (quite easy to see.) The general tactics include 1)seeing whether a part of function like here arctan (most of the trigonometric and inverse would have such max value) has some maximum finite value. 2) checking whether the function is odd so that integral is $0$. 3) checking the boundedness of a function like $e^{-x}\leq 1,x>0$.4) comparing the integral with known convergent integrals like Riemann Zeta, Gamma functions,Beta functions. The list may go on as each integral may require different technique.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I try to understand and test the "algorithm" for some other integrals. :)

Comment: (See also above.)

Comment: What should I see?